# what should be the datatype of utc_offset capturing using google place api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, google-maps-api-3

i am using google api for getting user information in a form, which has a field for timezone. i am binding utc_offset value that getting from google api.this value can be postive or -ve(eg:330 for india and -300 for US). i am using entity framework .so which datatype  should i have to use for saving the timezone.
i added one migration with

```
`public TimeZoneInfo{ get; set; }`
```

but this column is not updating in db.  can any one help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

First TimeZoneInfo is the wrong type.  You don't actually know which time zone the user is in, just the offset.  An UTC offset can be shared by multiple time zones with different daylight savings rules, etc.

A UTC offset is a duration.  The right .NET type is a TimeSpan, but there's no standard SQL type that maps to that.  For SQL Server EF will use [Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but you'll get a runtime error if you try to store a duration outside of the interval [0,24 hours).

So the right type for this is simply an `int`, and you'll need to keep track of the units of measure.  So something like:

```
public int UTCOffsetHours { get; set; }
```

Comment: ,thanks for the reply.if you don't mind can you explain in what scenario we will use the Timezoneinfo